# PAM Service - Autenticação externa por LDAP

Tags: linux, unix, openldap

Olá pessoal preciso de usa ajuda,

Minha aplicação roda utilizando um usuário de domínio e preciso acessa-la por um webservice utilizando esse usuário de AD com LDAP no linux, para isso estou utilizando o PAM Service, criei o arquivo appauth dentro de /etc/pam.d e fiz a seguinte configuração:

```
auth      sufficient    pam_unix.so use_first_pass
account   sufficient    pam_unix.so
```

Este é o erro:

```
pam_unix(appauth:auth): auth could not identify password for [webuser]
```

Fiquei na dúvida também entre utilizar o módulo pam_linux ou pam_ldap